# Error when BULK Insert from a DataTable to DB2

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, db2

I use WriteToServer() method of Db2BulkCopy class, in a .net project, to insert some data from data table into a table (db2). I got a very generic error that I don't know how to handle:

> the current transaction was rolled back because of error \"-952\"
>   {"ERROR [40506] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL1476N  The current transaction was rolled back because of error \"-952\"."}

I tried to add manually in database table a record and everything works.
Please offer some tips, if we encountered this before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The SQL1476N with code -952 is not generic, it is quite specific, you have to lookup the meaning of sqlcode -952 (aka. SQL0952N), and then you will find many hits.

Your Db2 client is timing out because the .Net defaults may be to wait for 30 seconds for any Db2 commnand to complete. You need to tell .Net to wait for a longer time to let your bulk copy complete. You can also tell .Net to wait forever.

The mechanism for varying the default query timeout depends on your Db2 client version and/or your coding techniques. You need to add QueryTimeout=0 property to the Db2 client or to the instance of the class in your code.

Older versions of the Db2 client had a db2cli.ini wherein you can specify this property. Current versions have a db2dsdriver.cfg file where you can specify this property. You can also specify the property either on the database connection string, or additionally by explicitly setting the relevant property in your code before runnning the BulkCopy.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the timeout and the issue appeared again. It seems that this was caused by the fact that a foreign key wasn't in the related table.
Thanks for everything!